# How to create a Certificate Authority 'CA' using pem lib NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, certificate-authority

Creating a CA using node

This is how to create a certificate using OpenSSL
[OpenSSL Certificate Authority](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/introduction.html)

I tried with [pem](https://github.com/Dexus/pem)

> This is my closed Issue [can't create CSR from private key #244](https://github.com/Dexus/pem/issues/244) **GitHub**

When I trying to generate a **CSR**

```
var csrOptions = {
    clientKey: '/root/ca/intermediate/private/client.key.pem',
    clientKeyPassword: '123456',
    hash: 'sha256',
    country: 'US',
    state: 'California',
    locality: 'Mountain View',
    organization: 'Alice Ltd',
    organizationUnit: 'Alice Ltd Web Services',
    commonName: 'pass:client',
}

pem.createCSR( csrOptions , function(err, csr) {
    if (err) {
        throw err
    } else {
        console.log(csr.clientKey)
        console.log(csr.csr)
    }

});
```

I get this error

> /root/sslnode/index2.js:37

> throw err
> ^

> % openssl req -new -sha256 -config /root/ca/intermediate/openssl.cnf -key /tmp/54f976cb9cbd0e2dd53b755badb6e6e3fe2256ad -passin file:/tmp/3f4640f1d95ca955f1c44c7f2c4b729347813a5f

> unable to load Private Key
> 140563986715072:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start >line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:691:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching I get the error, clientKey took a key as a string, not a path

> clientKey: '/root/ca/intermediate/private/client.key.pem',

```
clientKey: fs.readFileSync('/root/ca/intermediate/private/client.key.pem'),
```